# create loop for the_content()

Tags: theme-development

I want to create loop for the_content method to destroy content error
but I don't know how to create
this is what I have now:

```
 <div class="b-bottom">
     <p><?php the_modified_date('F Y') ?> | <a class="span_link" href="#"><?php the_modified_author(); ?> 
     </a></p>
     <p class="sub"><?php the_content();?></p>
</div>
```

and it have this error:'Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable'

How do I create a loop to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more context here? What are you trying to achieve? Also you should show the code that the error actually refers to.

Comment: I want to show details of posts in single page! and I am showing the code that creating error! It's the_content()